# How to set ListViewItem selected background color?

Tags: wpf, listview, listviewitem

Yes I know this is a possible duplicate but the answers I've seen just doesn't work (or I misunderstand). I cannot change the background color of the selected ListViewItem! This example is very simple and basic.

I have a list source defined like this:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApp5
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public List<ListViewItem> List
        {
            get
            {
                var list = new List<ListViewItem>();
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                {
                    list.Add(new ListViewItem
                    {
                        Height = 40,
                        Content = i,
                        VerticalContentAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center,
                        HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center
                    });
                }
            return list;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the XAML is just:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp5.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp5"
        x:Name="MainWindowName"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                <Style.Resources>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Black" />
                </Style.Resources>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true" >
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=MainWindowName, Path=List}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

As I understand it, some say the standard Style trigger works, while others say I need to set the `SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey`. Regardless, the above style changes nothing at all for the selected background. The foreground color is changed correct though?

Can someone post the correct XAML to change the background of the selected ListViewItem to black?

Thanks.

Comment: I know! the closest I've ever got is http://vbcity.com/blogs/xtab/archive/2009/06/28/background-color-for-wpf-listbox-selected-item.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you can't just set foreground/background and expect it to work, there are all sorts of other things going on such as highlights etc. The easiest thing in your case is probably to just replace the ListViewItem ControlTemplate with a TextBlock, then your foreground/background can be set via triggers.

Or to put it another way, just do this:

```
<Window.Resources>

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Style.Setters>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                            <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
                                <TextBlock Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center">
                                    <ContentPresenter />
                                </TextBlock>
                            </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
        </Style.Setters>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="PaleGoldenrod" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Yellow" />
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

</Window.Resources>
```